# How would you implement a partial request & response, like the youtube api, using ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

In the Youtube API, there is the power to request a ["partial feed"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial).

This allows the app developer to tailor the size and sturcture of the data returned, by specifying which "fields" to return.

i.e. `GET api/person/1?fields=(id,email)` would return a DTO containing only the `id` and the `email` fields, not the whole person response.

How would you attempt this using ServiceStack? Is there some way to attach a callback to the serialiser to control which properties to include in the response object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience servicestack only returns fields that actually has data. If my experience is correct then all you would need to do is figure out the best way to architect the request so that it is asking for specific data to return, this way you would only populate the response with data requested thus servicestack would only return that.

Comment: I did consider this method, and it may be the only possible way to do it. It seems like double handling to walk the property tree setting the fields you don't want to return to null, because the serialiser is going to walk the property tree again to output the json response.

Comment: There is a configuration property to control if nulls are returned or not. `JsConfig.IncludeNullValues`

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for value-typed DTO members.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this for an API that only returns JSON.

First I created two structs to (de)serialize and interpret the "fields" query argument recursive syntax:

- `FieldSelector`, which specifies a field and possibly its children `FieldSelection` enclosed between parenthesis;
- `FieldsSelection`, which is a comma-separated list of `FieldSelector`.

I've used structs instead of classes because, AFAIK, you can't override class (de)serialization from/to URLs in ServiceStack. With structs you can do it by overriding `ToString` (serializer) and providing a constructor accepting a string as parameter (deserializer).

Then you include this on every request DTO that returns JSON:

```
FieldsSelection Fields { get; set; }
```

On a custom `ServiceRunner<T>.OnAfterExecute` you serialize the response DTO to JSON, parse it with ServiceStack.Text's `JsonObject` and apply the fields selection recursively with a method like this:

```
private static JsonObject Apply(this JsonObject json, FieldsSelection fieldMask)
{
  IEnumerable<string> keysToRemove = json.Keys.ToList().Except(fieldMask.Keys);

  foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
    json.Remove(key);

  foreach (var selector in fieldMask.Selectors.Values.Where(s => s.HasSubFieldsSelection))
  {
    var field = json[selector.Field];
    if (field == null)
      continue;

    switch (field[0])
    {
      case '{':
        json[selector.Field] = Apply(json.Object(selector.Field), selector.SubFieldsSelection).ToJson();
        break;
      case '[':
        var itensArray = json.ArrayObjects(selector.Field);
        for (int i = 0; i < itensArray.Count; i++)
          itensArray[i] = Apply(itensArray[i], selector.SubFieldsSelection);
        json[selector.Field] = itensArray.ToJson();
        break;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentException("Selection incompatible with object structure");
    }
  }

  return json;
}
```

Then you return the result as your response DTO. I've also implemented negative fields selectors (`fields=-foo` selects all DTO fields except foo), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs) properties, they have all the hooks and customizations ServiceStack's text serializers support. Specifically the hooks that allow you to custom deserialization are:

```
JsConfig<T>.DeserializeFn 
JsConfig<T>.RawDeSerializeFn 
JsConfig<T>.OnDeserializedFn
```

Comment: I want to customise the Serialisation, not the Deserialise. I had a look at the JsConfig properties, and the ExcludePropertyNames is closest to what I need, but I didn't want to define it at the Type level, but on a per-request basis.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to implement said filtering by adding custom service runner and using some reflection in it to construct `ExpandoObject` with required field set by response DTO. See [this](http://s5315.socode.info/question/51502526e8432c042626c650) for more info on service runners.